# Synchronization Api in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created an application and created API to add categories,products but I Need a API  for synchronization like If any product is updated by magento admin then updated product will be shown to application.Similarly If any product is deleted by magento admin then this product will also be  be deleted from APPlication .

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you have to create another API which will be triggered on each product update event.

There are observers `<catalog_product_save_after>` and `<catalog_controller_product_delete>` for deletion.

In Api code, you just send a flag with product id that x product has been deleted or send product data in case of product updated.